# How to add an existing VM instance to an instance group to enable autoscaling?

Tags: virtual-machines, groups, google-compute-engine, autoscaling, multiple-instances

we have two VM instances running in Google Compute Engine.
The first one is running NodeJs instances that connect to a mongodb server installed on the second VM instance.
Those have CPU higher running most of the time around 70%.

I would like to add autoscaling to these instances in order to improve the performances but I don't want to reinstall the instances completely and to keep the public and internal ip adresses if possible.

If I am right, I have to create a new group instance and add the two existing instances to it.

My questions are the following:

1. Will it keep my instances running and with the same IPs, firewall settings... ?
2. Is it the right way to proceed or is there a way to just increase the CPU of my existing instances as required?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoscaling feature of managed instance groups is usually applicable to stateless VM instances. An autoscaler adds or removes instances from a managed instance group. Therefore, any data stored on root disks of VMs can be lost.

For your NodeJs VM, you can use autoscaler if it's a stateless VM. However, for MongoDB VM one option is upgrading the [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) of your VM and increase the processing resources to accommodate your workloads. This is called `Vertical Scaling`. Another option is implementing the `Horizontal Scaling` through [sharding feature](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) of MongoDB.

About your other questions:

To keep your IP external address, if it's an ephemeral one you can [promote it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) to a static external IP address and assign it to the forwarding rule of a [HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/). The load balancer will distribute user requests among your NodeJs VM instances (Backends).

Your GCE firewall rules might need to be modified to comply with [Load balancer requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#firewall_rules).

Comment: Thanks a lot sounds clear to me regarding the MongoDB VM but not enough yet regarding the nodejs one.
Will have a look at it. Thanks